# How to render data selected choice on templates with bootstrap in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Im Create Gender with field ('jenis_kelamin') in my models
Male('Pria') and Female('Wanita').

But, when i post the data, data is not render.

display on my template.
[DISPLAY ON MY TEMPLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98LLD.png)

display on my Admin Page.
[DISPLAY ON MY ADMIN PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez0Qe.png)

How to Fix That ?
This is My :

**models.py**

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
JENIS_KELAMIN_CHOICE = (
    ('Pria', 'Pria'),
    ('Wanita', 'Wanita' ),
)

#Profil
user                    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
gelar_depan             = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, default="")
gelar_belakang          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
nik                     = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
nidn                    = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
email_alternatif        = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True, default="")
jenis_kelamin           = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, default="", choices =JENIS_KELAMIN_CHOICE)
tempat_lahir            = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, unique=True, default="")
tanggal_lahir           = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
nomor_handphone         = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
alamat                  = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfilUpdateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model           = UserProfil
    exclude         = ['user']

    widgets = {
        'gelar_depan'       : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarDepan', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Depan'}),
        'gelar_belakang'    : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Belakang'}),
        'nidn'              : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nidn', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Dosen Nasional'}),
        'nik'               : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Karyawan'}),
        'tempat_lahir'      : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tempat Lahir'}),
        'tanggal_lahir'     : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tanggal Lahir', 'type' : 'date'}),
        'nomor_handphone'   : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'No Handphone'}),
        'email_alternatif'  : forms.EmailInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'emailAlternatif', 'placeholder' : 'Email Alternatif'}),
        'alamat'            : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'alamat', 'placeholder' : 'Alamat'}),
        'jenis_kelamin'     : forms.Select({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'jenisKelamin',}),
    }
```

Comment: The other fields are rendered correctly?

Comment: Did you try add default for `jenis_kelamin`? For example: `jenis_kelamin = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, default="Pria", choices =JENIS_KELAMIN_CHOICE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you form doesn't save is be because you omitted the forms from   the UserProfilUpdateForm instead of this (forms.ModelForm) you did this (ModelForm) which wouldn't work and also you didn't add your fields to the Meta class which wont work eithe, if there are no fields

```
class UserProfilUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = UserProfil
            fields = ['jenis_kelamin','gelar_depan',
            'gelar_belakang','nidn','nik','tempat_lahir',
             'tanggal_lahir','nomor_handphone','email_alternatif','alamat' ]
          

            widgets = {
        'gelar_depan'       : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarDepan', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Depan'}),
        'gelar_belakang'    : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Gelar Belakang'}),
        'nidn'              : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nidn', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Dosen Nasional'}),
        'nik'               : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Induk Karyawan'}),
        'tempat_lahir'      : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tempat Lahir'}),
        'tanggal_lahir'     : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'gelarBelakang', 'placeholder' : 'Tanggal Lahir', 'type' : 'date'}),
        'nomor_handphone'   : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'nik', 'placeholder' : 'No Handphone'}),
        'email_alternatif'  : forms.EmailInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'emailAlternatif', 'placeholder' : 'Email Alternatif'}),
        'alamat'            : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'alamat', 'placeholder' : 'Alamat'}),
        'jenis_kelamin'     : forms.Select({'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'jenisKelamin',}),
    }
```